# AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2 NuGet package

Tags: nuget, autofac, nuget-package

I'm having problems getting `AutofactContrib.DynamicProxy2` installed.
When trying to get the `AutofactContrib.DynamicProxy2` NuGet package, I get the following error:

> PM> install-package AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Autofac (≥ 2.4.5.724)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Castle.Core (≥ 2.5.2)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Castle.DynamicProxy (≥ 2.2.0)'.
>   Attempting to resolve dependency 'Castle.Core (= 1.2.0)'.
>   Install-Package : Updating 'Castle.Core 2.5.2' to 'Castle.Core 1.2.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2' that is compatible with 'Castle.Core 1.2.0'. At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

As far as I understand, in Castle V.3 there's no longer a `DynamicProxy.dll` but it's contained in `Castle.Core.dll`.
I guess that I have to install a previous version of `Castle.Core.dll`, but for some reason the package has a dependency on `'Castle.Core (≥ 2.5.2)'`, so even if I manually install `Castle.Core` V. 1.2, I still get this error.
Anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `-ignoredependencies`, It works with `targetFramework="net40"`.

```
PM> install-package autofaccontrib.dynamicproxy2 -ignoredependencies
```

You can install Dependencies separately

```
Autofac(≥ 2.4.5.724)
Castle.Core(≥ 2.5.2)
Castle.DynamicProxy(≥ 2.2.0)
```

**Result**:

```
PM> install-package autofaccontrib.dynamicproxy2 -ignoredependencies
Successfully installed 'AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2 2.4.5.724'.
Successfully added 'AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2 2.4.5.724' to StackOverflow2.

PM>
```

Comment: almost- there are some inconsistencies with the dependencies for Castle.DynamicProxy as well, so i ended up installing everything (`autofaccontrib.dynamicproxy2`, `Castle.Core`, `Castle.DynamicProxy`) with the `ignoredependencies` flag